# SVG CSS Transform animation, cross-browser issues

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I am working on a simple hamburger-menu SVG icon for a website I'm building. To make the often-used icon a bit less boring, I thought it would be nice to have a bit of animation in it. I decided to make the three horizontal bars rotate (each one separately) to form a cross.

As I'm developing on a Mac, Safari was the first browser I tested it in, and everything worked exactly as intended. But then I decided to open the same file in Firefox, to see that the animation was broken. On further investigating the issue, I noticed that inverting the order of the CSS transforms applied to the bars had the exact opposite effect: The result in Firefox was perfect, while Safari displayed the icon incorrectly.

The simplified code for the hamburger icon:

```
<svg id="hamburger" viewBox="0 0 30 30" width="30" height="30">
  <rect id="top" x="0" y="8px" width="30" height="2"/>
  <rect id="middle" x="0" y="15px" width="30" height="2"/>
  <rect id="bottom" x="0" y="22px" width="30" height="2"/>
</svg>
```

The animation was added in an Sass-file with the following code:

```
#top,
#middle,
#bottom {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: none;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

#hamburger.active {
  #top {
    transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  #middle {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  #bottom {
    transform: translateY(- 7px) rotate(45deg);
  }
}
```

The strange thing is, that when the order of the `translate` and `rotate` transforms is turned around, the two different browsers show the exact opposite result. I understand that the order of the transforms can affect the final result (although I think in this case it shouldn't), but I don't understand why the 'compatibility' is inverted by switching the order.

I have created 2 almost identical Codepen-examples with the above code. The only difference is the order of the `translate` and `rotate` transforms:

- Works in Safari, broken in Firefox:
  http://codepen.io/Dimiter/pen/jrBqry
- Broken in Safari, works in Firefox: http://codepen.io/Dimiter/pen/vKxGRY

*Correct, working animation:*

[image]

*Broken animation:*

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for your question.
This is a really interesting issue with Firefox.
I tested both cases and indeed webkit has no issues with your code, while firefox is misplacing the elements.

I think this might be due to transform-origin differences across browsers.

Either way I was able to help your hamburger become a cross in firefox, by addind a -moz-transition property with a little different values for the transform.

Try updating your code to this, and tell me if it solves your issue :)

```
#hamburger.active {
  #top {
    transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: translate(-5px,3px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  #middle {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  #bottom {
    transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: translate(5px,-7px) rotate(45deg);
  }
}
```

Also remember to write negative values without a space. So like this *"-7px"* and not like this *"- 7px"*

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This indeed fixes the issue. I think it is due to this specific bug in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209061#c0 . And I was aware of the minus, but luckily Sass compiles that to the correct form :)

Comment: A bit late, but here is a bit more information. This isn't broken in either browser. The browsers have different defaults set for `transform-box`. That is what controls the reference box for `transform-origin`. Firefox sets it to the SVG wrapper. Safari and Chrome set it to the element being transformed. Currently, FF is correct per the spec. However, spec might be changing. See here for more details: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209061#c6